# NextJS decode google auth id_token

Tags: authentication, next.js, token, decode

I have a project that connects to a socket. This socket is separated itself from nextjs project. In order for this socket project to be protected it should accept a token that is passed from nextjs and verify if a token is valid. However, upon decoding/verifying the token using jsonwebtoken with the GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET in env, it says a message that can be seen below **(JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm)**.

Tried adding an option `{ algorithms: "ALL ALGO OPTIONS" }` after "mySecret"

[image]

I also try other secret key like **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** and this one **GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID**. But still no luck. Anyone encounter this and how didyou solve it?

Thank you.